# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'component') Vue 2 Konva

Tags: vuejs2, konvajs, vue-konva

- The Vue Konva setup runs properly on local dev envs
- After building the app as it fails to find v-stage tag and Konva component also

Versions being used
"vue": "^2.6.14",
"vue-konva": "^2.1.7",
"konva": "^8.3.10",

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJhtA.png)

```
import VueKonva from 'vue-konva'
import App from 'file'

window.Vue.use(VueKonva)
window.custom.extension.register('#ext-size-comparison-view', {
    mounted(element) {
        window.FPI.extension.mountApp({
            element,
            component: App,
        })
    },
})
```

Error Message

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'component')
at Module.<anonymous> (vue-konva.js:304:106)
at r (vue-konva.js:34:30)
at Object.<anonymous> (vue-konva.js:111:18)
at r (vue-konva.js:34:30)
at vue-konva.js:98:18
at vue-konva.js:15:17
at vue-konva.js:7:20
at 6168 (vue-konva.js:5:1)
```

Comment: Please post the code or error as text in question, not an image.

Comment: @toyotaSupra added detailed message